# SQL help: find rows in one table which don't exist in second table based on values in two columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables. I am trying to find rows in one table which do not exist in second table based on values in two columns. (I have simplified the tables to include the two columns only). There are no primary/foreign keys between the two tables. Seems simple enough but I am having a brain block now!

```
DDL:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [firstname] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [lastname] [nchar](10) NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_2](
    [firstname] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [lastname] [nchar](10) NULL
)
```

-- create sample data

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([firstname], [lastname])
SELECT N'John      ', N'Doe       ' UNION ALL
SELECT N'John      ', N'Smith     '
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_2]([firstname], [lastname])
SELECT N'John      ', N'Doe       '
```

--My failed attempts. I am expecting John smith to return

```
SELECT t.* FROM Table_1 AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT t2.* FROM Table_2 AS t2
WHERE t.firstname <> t2.firstname
AND t.lastname <> t2.lastname)

SELECT * FROM Table_1 AS t
JOIN Table_2 AS t2
ON t.firstname <> t2.firstname
AND t.lastname <> t2.lastname
```

Comment: Please say you aren't really using nchar datatypes for names. Also without any other identifying information how would you know that John Smith in table1 is the same John Smith as in table2? Names are not unique and you shouldn't plan on them being so. While the queries below may gove you the results you expect, they may not give correct results.

Comment: It's just an example I whipped quickly. yes it should be nvarchar and people are unique even if names are the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1 AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 AS t2
ON t1.firstname = t2.firstname
AND t1.lastname = t2.lastname
WHERE t2.firstname IS NULL AND t2.lastname IS NULL
```

In my case, I get only John Smith back.

You basically do an **outer join** between the tables on the common fields - those rows that are present in both cases will have values for both `t1` and `t2`.

Those rows only present in `t1` will not have any values for the second table `t2`.

Comment: My first query should have = instead of <>. I was copying stuff around and forgot to notice this. Thanks.

Comment: How can I change this query to remove those selected rows?

Comment: @Mateusz: you could "wrap" it into a CTE `;WITH CTE AS (SELECT.....)` and then add a `DELETE FROM Table_1 WHERE CTE.IDColumn = .....` or something like that...

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT t.* FROM Table_1 AS t
 LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2 ON (t.firstname = t2.firstname AND t.lastname = t2.lastname)
WHERE t2.firstname IS NULL AND t2.lastname IS NULL
```

But I'm surprised that your first try didn't work:

```
SELECT t.* FROM Table_1 AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT t2.* FROM Table_2 AS t2
WHERE t.firstname <> t2.firstname
AND t.lastname <> t2.lastname)
```

Comment: that second query would have to check for **equality** (not inequality) on the firstname and lastname columns ! If you do so, it works, too.  `...... WHERE t.firstname = t2.firstname
AND t.lastname = t2.lastname`

Answer (score 1):

Outer joins are  fine but I find this method typically executes faster on large amounts of data.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM Table_2 AS t2
        WHERE t1.firstname = t2.firstname
            AND t1.lastname = t2.lastname
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try a left outer join using both columns in the ON clause.

Then use the WHERE clause to filter out anything where both tables match

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 AS one
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 AS two
ON one.firstname = two.firstname
AND one.lastname = two.lastname
WHERE two.firstname IS NULL AND two.lastname IS NULL
```